# Transferring two columns of data to two mode network in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two columns of data like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi5Gu.jpg)

and it will be a very long list, and i want to transfer it to two mode network matrix using R language, where first column is the names list (without repetition, because in raw data many names are repeated) and the row will be the activity (also without repetition), it will be something like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0dZM.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: i have just answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208966/mapping-dataframe-column-values-to-a-n-by-n-matrix)

Comment: Also from the R-Tag you have used in your question: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) along with the desired end result. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks.** For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. In this case (it appears to be excel, not R), I think you could easily manually generate some data with `data.frame(...)` and put that *code* in your question. It would go a long way to making the data something we can use and play with. (Since this is a duplicate and the two links above have good examples, I think you should be "good".)